# PHP foreach variable scope issue

Tags: php

I have an array full of associative arrays like so:

```
$arr = [
  ['title' => 'My title', 'content' => 'lorem ...', comments: 'lorem ipsum'],
  ['title' => 'My title 2', 'content' => 'lorem ...'],
  ['title' => 'My title 3', 'content' => 'lorem ...'],
  ['title' => 'My title 4', 'content' => 'lorem ...', comments: 'lorem ipsum'],
];
```

As you can see, some of them don't have `comments`.

The problem is, I have then a foreach loop like this:

```
<?php foreach($arr as $key => $value){
  extract($value);
?>
  <div>
    ...etc
    <?php if($comment): ?>
       <span><?= $comment ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

In the second iteration, the variable `$comments` now holds the value of the first item in the array, cause it doesn't find the property in the associative array and it uses the last one, breaking the `if` statement.

Is there any way to avoid this without having to add a `comments: null` or something to the original array?

Comment: Doesn’t use extract. Properly name your variables. Your IDE will also be happy about that.

Comment: is `list('comments' => $comments)` etc.. any better?

Comment: `if (isset($value['comment'])) { ... }`

Comment: No use the array. You're just making a mess pulling values out of the array. You could if you must, at the end of the loop unset $comment and all other variables you create on each iteration

Comment: In PHP variables are scoped to the function, not the iteration block. So a variable set in a loop doesn't go away when the loop repeats.

Comment: Do not use `extract()`. You don't need it. Ever.

Comment: @axiac not necessary. `extract()`, when  ̶c̶o̶r̶r̶e̶c̶t̶l̶y̶ used, leads quickly to a code impossible to maintain, and therefore, grants a lifetime job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to check if variable `$elem['comments']` exists:

```
<div>
<?php
foreach($arr as $key => $elem){
    if(isset($elem['comments'])){
        // Comments exists here
        echo "<span>".$elem['comments']."</span>";
    }else{
        // Comments do not exists here, so don't echo anything
    }
}
?>
</div>
```

Or use [array_key_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) to check if `comments` key is in array `elem`:

```
<?php
foreach($arr as $key => $elem){
    if(array_key_exists('comments', $elem)) {
        // Comments exists here
        echo "<span>".$elem['comments']."</span>";
    }else{
        // Comments do not exists here, so don't echo anything
    }
}
?>
```

Take notice that:

> isset() does not return TRUE for array keys that correspond to a NULL
>   value, while array_key_exists() does.

So in your use case I would recommend you to use `isset` as you discard existing `comments` keys with `null` values the same way as if `comments` keys do not exists.